# Changing main URL

Tags: url, installation, base-url

I am just after some advice if someone could kindly help me. I am very new to Magento having been a big Woo Commerce fan in Wordpress (now converted!)

When I set up my website, I initially set up Wordpress and then added Magento on a /magento page. I now want Magento on the first page and then delete my Wordpress site (but does that all make sense?)

I thought it would be easy by deleting Wordpress, then changing the base url in Magento's configuration page but every time I do, I lose the site and admin site permanently. Not being over technical, I am confused and just need someone to point me in the right direction.

I was wondering if it was something to do with the .htaccess file?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

go to your magento table core_config_data and change the url in these 2 fields

`web/secure/base_url`  and `web/unsecure/base_url`

make sure to add / after your url and clear cache once you done with it.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the base url is the right thing to do. Check your .htaccess if it is doing a redirect for magento/index.php to magento or something that was specific to that set up and doesn't work anymore.

Another thing is  - Are you changing your host to point to root/magento and not to just root any more?